# Unable to create log files in EC2 instance using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-logging

I am running a script in EC2 instance as job (through task scheduler) which creates its own log file. On my local machine it runs perfectly fine and creates the file, but on EC2 i'm not able to see the file at all.

Here is the sample code

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

def setup_logging(logger, logfile):
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        logfile, maxBytes=(1048576 * 5), backupCount=7)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)


logfile = 'one_time_loader'
logger = logging.getLogger()
setup_logging(logger, logfile)

for i in range(0,1000):
    logger.info(i)
```

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import Boto3 from the AWS SDK. https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/ Since you're running it as an EC2 instance type, you'll need to make calls against the Resource APIs. See the doc for more information.

Comment: could you a provide a little more detail to it? I'm having trouble figuring how to use it. The issue is that when i login to the server it will create the file, but if i'm not logged and script runs there's no log file created.

Comment: In that scenario, I'd say have a service account created in IAM and create a cron job/scheduled task that is linked to the account. The service account may actually not be needed per the steps provided in this link. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html